# how to read txt or csv file with javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, cors, phonegap, txt

I am trying to fill an array from an Excelsheet. I have tried many attempts but in an other post I had a partial answer.

> ```
> CSV is a format more portable than XLS which can be exported from excel. 
> This format is easy to be parsed (try to export a CSV file from XLS in excel and open it with a text editor by yourself!). 
> If this change in format is acceptable, the problem can be simplified quite a lot.
> ```

I made .csv and also a .txt folder on my desktop but I am not able to read it. I have tried many html/js code and I have encountered this answer from the console.

> testexcel.html:43 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'file:///C:/exceltest2.1.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol
> schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted,
> https.

or with fetch the same

> Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/ubi11/Desktop/exceltest2.1.txt.
> URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request. getData @
> testexcel.html:15 (anonymous) @ testexcel.html:12

I tried to put my file in google drive then:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XxRJeH2yOyAmatnhj-zF2CsGz1R3WzQk/view?usp=sharing'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What is CORS policy? is there a way to read a file and parse what is inside? if there is no solution, can I do what I need through GoogleSheet or will I have the same problem?
I actually need to do something easy, read a list of numbers in 4 columns. I don't want to put this list neither in the js code nor in an sql database.
TY

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have tried ?

Comment: Cors is a security policy for browser. Mozilla provides great explanation on its purpose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Before you worry too much about the file format like CSV (that's the easy part), you need to understand how to interact with files using a web browser and JavaScript. Please start here and read all of this carefully: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: well it seems very complicated for a newbie to go all through this. there is no solution for such a simple thing.
what do you suggest ? going through a server? googlesheet?(i had the same cors problem with google drive)